# Transfering from ubuntu to windows

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I recently bought an ssd and it is plugged in correctly, however I would like to create a dual boot on my ssd with with windows and ubuntu. The problem is my Ubuntu is already installed on my 2tb hard drive How can I get my computer to boot into the ssd and/or transfer ubuntu onto the ssd and the install ubuntu. There is nothing on the hard drive that I need to save. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend a fresh install, if its all possible.

Comment: Probably not a recommended/real answer, but install ubuntu and windows on the ssd, and empty the ubuntu partition and copy/paste the ubuntu from the 2tb? Maybe it won't work, maybe it will, but I guess you can always try it. (Yes I would try this myself :P, maybe you will break grub, just use a live cd to fix it)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu!

It's quite simple if you don't want to save anything! Simply install Windows over the whole disk. Then use the Ubuntu `live-dvd` or `live usb` to install Ubuntu and choose the `Install next to Windows` option.